# Coffescript, Jaml like template engine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, template-engine, jaml

I'm just experimenting the various javascript template engines (client-side) for my backbone views...

And i found this old project: https://github.com/edspencer/jaml

It seems good to me, because i dont have to use of long string blocks like other template engines (like handlebars or underscore..)

The problem is that Jaml is really outdated, and it seems there's no successor to it...

Someone has new resources to share about?

As always, i'm sorry for my bad english :S

Answer (score 1):

[Haml-coffee](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml-coffee) might be what you are looking for. It works very well with Backbone too.

Answer (score 1):

The most common "haml-style" template engine for javascript is probably [jade](http://jade-lang.com/).

Another which might interest you, since you're a fan of coffeescript, is [CoffeeKup](http://coffeekup.org/).